# SQL query for getting count and distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table called `user_pin_tags` with the following data that I need to query and show distinct tags and a count of each:

```
| user_id | pin_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+--------+
    1     |   34   |   7
    2     |   34   |   7
    3     |   34   |   15   
    4     |   34   |   16   
    5     |   34   |   16   
    6     |   34   |   16
```

Right now I am using the following query to get the distinct tag_ids

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag_id
FROM user_pin_tags
WHERE pin_id =  34
```

which gives the result of:

```
| tag_id |
+--------+
    7
    15
    16
```

I need to modify this query to give the distinct tag_ids as well as the count within that pin_id, so I want to generate this result set:

```
| tag_id | count |
+--------+-------+
    7    |   2
    15   |   1
    16   |   3
```

How can I modify this query to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

```
SELECT tag_id, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM user_pin_tags
WHERE pin_id =  34
GROUP BY tag_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT(tag_id)
   ,count(pin_id)
FROM user_pin_tags
WHERE pin_id =  34
GROUP BY tag_id
```

Group By should do it ... i think.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the tag_id:

```
SELECT tag_id, COUNT(pin_id)
FROM user_pin_tags
WHERE pin_id =  34
GROUP BY tag_id
```